# Apple submission requirements for iPhone apps

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

Im not sure what the implications of point 2.10 of Apples requirements implies. 2.10 states "iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution"

If I write an iPhone app that works will it be enough to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Try it out in the iPad simulator at least.

Comment: If you're not going out of your way to explicitly disallow this from happening, you're almost certainly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is yes. To make an app work on an iPhone, but not on the iPad you would have to try to limit the features by checking if the device is an iPad and then purposely not working.

If you do not do anything like that, your app will no be rejected based on that requirement.