# Is it required to make my app "universal" for AppStore approval?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I almost uploaded my app, but read the following in the App Store guidelines:

> iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone
>   resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

I can't figure out what does it mean exactly so I would really appreciate if somebody could help me to choose the right way.

1. Do I need to create an "universal app"?

or

1. I don't need to make my app "universal", but its functions must work on the iPad?

I tried both, and the layout looks much better on the iPad when it's not an universal app. Is it possible that I target the iPhone in the deployment info, but it's still works on the iPad? Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Some info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942593/apple-submission-requirements-for-iphone-apps?rq=1)

Comment: @PavelOganesyan thank you, I didn't saw that question. But possibly could you tell me, that can I target my app only to the iPhone instead of universal? As I see now, the universal option is needed when you want a design for the iPad too. Is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not forced to make app universal, but you have to be sure that it will not crash on any device. This means that user can install you app on iPad too, use it, maybe with some restrictions, but it will not behave bad enough to be rejected by Apple testers in review.
For example, you have a specific iPhone only option. User presses the button to use it and:

1. Apps crashes - rejection.
2. Apps shows message "Only for iPhones" - possibly ok.

More than that - you need to avoid universal app to be sure compatibility mode will be used. If your app is universal, you should provide iPad support (resources, nib and so on) by yourself.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527781/make-an-iphone-specific-app-work-on-ipad-to-meet-apple-requirements?rq=1) question is also helpful.

[Yet another proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946966/is-it-important-for-an-app-to-work-on-both-iphone-and-ipad?rq=1)

Comment: Great, so I can target only to the iPhone, but it must work on the iPad. In this case do I need to edit any iPad related stuff in the plist? Or just care about the working functionality?

Comment: @vv88  I'd say - just functionality and no manual changes in iPad section of the plist since you are not targeting iPad, but I'd like to hear someone else prove me wright/wrong to be sure.

Comment: Great, I don't have to make it universal in my case and that's the point. I'll upload it and give a feedback if it's rejected because the plist issue.